# A few millions results or a few million result

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

> I have a few millions results

vs

> I have a few million results

Which one is grammatical?

Answer (score 2):

You don't pluralize numbers unless it's followed by *of something.* For example:

> I have *millions of* results.
>
> It will cost *hundreds of* dollars

In every other context I can think of, million (or thousand, billion, trillion etc.) should be singular.

> I have a few million results.
>
> I have a couple million results.
>
> I have several million results
>
> I have *X* million results.

Comment: Do you mean "pluralise"?