# "31 million answers compared to 11 million" or 11 millions?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, numbers

I read on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361097/178179:

> [Stack Overflow has] more than 31 million answers, compared to 11 **million** for the rest of the network.

Should million be in plural of singular form? I don't know what the correct rule is here since "answers" implicitly follows million.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A few millions results or a few million result](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/a-few-millions-results-or-a-few-million-result)

Comment: Another suggestion: [Why is there no plural 's' after “hundred” or “thousand” in cardinal numbers?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38635/why-is-there-no-plural-s-after-hundred-or-thousand-in-cardinal-numbers)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the suggestions, it is a different question because in my question I don't know what the correct rule is here since "answers" implicitly follows million.

Comment: Specific numbers are used in the singular, when there is a noun or implied noun following. So there might be 11 million, or 11 million answers, but there are 'millions **of** answers'.

Comment: @WeatherVane got it, thanks! You're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no plural 's' after "hundred" or "thousand" in cardinal numbers?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38635/why-is-there-no-plural-s-after-hundred-or-thousand-in-cardinal-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The word million can be used as a noun or an adjective in English. [million](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/million)
2. In your example "million" is an adjective.
3. We don't pluralise adjectives

Let us substitute a different adjective. We will substitute "good" for "million".

*[Stack Overflow has] more than 31 good answers, compared to 11 good for the rest of the network.*

"11 good" is an abbreviation for "11 good answers".